# MVC and Android as front-ends WebApi as backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I am going to build an application with two different front-ends.
the first one is a website which I intend to build it with MVC5 and the second one is with Android platform.

Question: 
what is the best practice to accomplish this goal?

should I make the WebApi in charge of working with the lower layers of my application and make call to it via Android and HttpClient (for MVC) or just make my website with MVC and find the specific needed APIs to be called by Android platform afterwards?

I feel something wrong with having a facade (MVC controllers) on top of another facade(WebAPI controllers) meanwhile I can not find any better architecture for these kind of software.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having an mvc application call an api, however you would probably not be using the whole framework, so it might be the case of just using mvc to handle routing, and the rest of the logic happen in javascript that calls the webapi with ajax. Your webapi will then have all the business logic (and data layers) that the website and android application needs.

Comment: I am using the same Architecture in my current project, every thing went well, but when you reach to user authentication and authorization it will be tough side with very less help available on line. I found this blog : https://wesleycabus.be/2014/06/adding-an-mvc-layer-on-top-of-a-web-api-backend/

Answer (score 0):

If to start with, you keep the classes with the functionality seperate from your MVC or WebAPI controller code, you can share this between the 2.  It can be cleaner to put your Application / Business logic in a separate csproj all together, then reference from your MVC and WebAPI.  This will also make it easier to test that code.

This then gives you the option of developing your app MVC first, test with users and get feedback (without spending time on APIs etc yet), and then build your API afterwards for android (using the same application code).  You could also end up with both running on top of the API, which arguably would be a better long term place to be for maintenance and security.  This evolutionary approach will tend to help you avoid over engineering your software.